# JavaCV/OpenCV cvDrawContours modifies original image

Tags: opencv, javacv

I am experimenting with JavaCV (OpenCV) and I am confused with the following behavior.
My programm simply:

1. Grab an image
2. Create a grayscale version of the image (leaving the original image untouched)
3. Threshold the grayscale image
4. Find contours in the grayscale image (cloning the image since cvFindContours modifies the image and we want to display it as is)
5. Draw contours **on the original color image**

The problem is that unless I clone the `grabbedImage` (see commented line), the grayscale image is modified and contours are drawn on it. Also, it is as if multiple contours are drawn on the `grabbedImage`.

I also tried to add a sleep to the loop and it fixes the problem. Could it be that I get the same (modified) `grabbedImage` multiple time? I checked the java reference and it's different but could it be the same buffer?

Any idea?

Thank you

```
package com.mdarveau.opencvtest;

import static com.googlecode.javacv.cpp.opencv_core.*;
import static com.googlecode.javacv.cpp.opencv_imgproc.*;

import com.googlecode.javacpp.Loader;
import com.googlecode.javacv.CanvasFrame;
import com.googlecode.javacv.FrameGrabber;
import com.googlecode.javacv.cpp.opencv_core.CvContour;
import com.googlecode.javacv.cpp.opencv_core.CvMemStorage;
import com.googlecode.javacv.cpp.opencv_core.CvScalar;
import com.googlecode.javacv.cpp.opencv_core.CvSeq;
import com.googlecode.javacv.cpp.opencv_core.IplImage;
import com.googlecode.javacv.cpp.opencv_objdetect;

public class Demo {

    public static void main( String[] args ) throws Exception {
        // Preload the opencv_objdetect module to work around a known bug.
        Loader.load( opencv_objdetect.class );

        FrameGrabber grabber = FrameGrabber.createDefault( 1 );
        grabber.start();

        IplImage grabbedImage = grabber.grab();
        int width = grabbedImage.width();
        int height = grabbedImage.height();

        IplImage grayImage = IplImage.create( width, height, IPL_DEPTH_8U, 1 );

        CvMemStorage storage = CvMemStorage.create();

        CanvasFrame filterProbe = new CanvasFrame( "Filtered", CanvasFrame.getDefaultGamma() / grabber.getGamma() );
        CanvasFrame enhancedProbe = new CanvasFrame( "Enhanced", CanvasFrame.getDefaultGamma() / grabber.getGamma() );

        while ( filterProbe.isVisible() && enhancedProbe.isVisible() && (grabbedImage = grabber.grab()) != null ) {
            cvClearMemStorage( storage );

            // Convert to grayscale image...
            cvCvtColor( grabbedImage, grayImage, CV_BGR2GRAY );
            // UNCOMMENT FIXES THE PROBLEM grabbedImage = grabbedImage.clone();

            // Let's find some contours! but first some thresholding...
            cvThreshold( grayImage, grayImage, 128, 255, CV_THRESH_BINARY );

            // To check if an output argument is null we may call either isNull() or equals(null).
            CvSeq contour = new CvSeq( null );
            // cvFindContours modifies the image so clone it first since we want to keep the grayscale version
            cvFindContours( grayImage.clone(), storage, contour, Loader.sizeof( CvContour.class ), CV_RETR_LIST, CV_CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE );
            while ( contour != null && !contour.isNull() ) {
                if ( contour.elem_size() > 0 ) {
                    CvSeq points = cvApproxPoly( contour, Loader.sizeof( CvContour.class ), storage, CV_POLY_APPROX_DP, cvContourPerimeter( contour ) * 0.02, 0 );
                    cvDrawContours( grabbedImage, points, CvScalar.BLUE, CvScalar.BLUE, -1, 1 /*CV_FILLED*/, CV_AA );
                }
                contour = contour.h_next();
            }

            filterProbe.showImage( grayImage );
            enhancedProbe.showImage( grabbedImage );
        }
        filterProbe.dispose();
        enhancedProbe.dispose();
        grabber.stop();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

This is the expected behavior of [cvFindContours()](http://docs.opencv.org/modules/imgproc/doc/structural_analysis_and_shape_descriptors.html#int%20cvFindContours%28CvArr%2a%20image,%20CvMemStorage%2a%20storage,%20CvSeq%2a%2a%20first_contour,%20int%20header_size,%20int%20mode,%20int%20method,%20CvPoint%20offset%29):

> The function modifies the image while extracting the contours.